# When building a Ruby gem, how do you specify which files Bundler should require?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, require

In the past, based on a stylistic decision, I've created gems that use use names containing dashes:

```
foo-bar
```

However, the folder structure under `lib` looks more like this:

```
lib
  foo_bar.rb
```

If I use one of my own gems in the Gemfile of another project, Bundler doesn't require the library automatically. If I use one of my single word named gems (`bundy` for example) in another project's Gemfile, the auto-require works.

Based on the default structure of a gem project created with Bundler, I'm guessing that Bundler is trying to require the contents of `lib/foo/bar.rb`. Unknown to me, gems seem to expect a '-' in the gem name to relate to a '/' in the path name.

What if I want Bundler to require `lib/foo_bar.rb`? Can this be done without:

- Changing the name of the gem? (Some gems are in use in projects owned by companies I no longer work for, so I don't want to do this.)
- Adding extraneous files to manage includes? (Seems messy and unprofessional.)
- Adding an explicit require to the 'gem' declaration in the Gemfile? (Seems unprofessional.)

Comment: can you post the log error from bundler? Is it something like a LoadError : can't find file `lib/foo/bar` ?

Comment: The problem won't appear in any logs, @floum, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the Bundler code, I found that the auto-require path comes from one of two places:

- The 'require' setting in the Gemfile
- The name of the gem itself.

  ```
  #/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
  ...    
  if options.key?('require')
    @autorequire = Array(options['require'] || [])
  end
  ...
  ```

and:

```
      #/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
      ...
      if dep.autorequire.nil? && dep.name.include?('-')
        begin
          namespaced_file = dep.name.gsub('-', '/')
          Kernel.require namespaced_file
        rescue LoadError => e
          REQUIRE_ERRORS.find { |r| r =~ e.message }
          raise if $1 != namespaced_file
        end
      end
      ...
```

This replaces the `-` characters in the gem's name with '/', just as I found from my experiments. From the looks of it, it also swallows the exception if it encounters a require error trying to require the transformed gem name. (It re-throws for others, so presumably it will fail if a gem's internal dependencies are broken.)

I can't find any other mechanism for setting an autorequire file, so I'll grudgingly have to use my second option: add an extra file in the location that Bundler expects which requires the files I need.

Comment: This is correct; foo-bar is autoloaded as `foo/bar.rb`. You can either change the name of your gem to foo_bar, or add a foo/bar.rb loader stub. This form exists because of the popularity of gems which extend other gems, such as `sidekiq-scheduler`, which loads sidekiq/scheduler and exposes a `Sidekiq::Scheduler` module, rather than loading `sidekiq_scheduler` and exposing a `SidekiqScheduler` module.

Comment: Yes, I can see the usefulness. I just wish I'd known before I built and released my gems! ;) Stub files it is.

Answer (score -1):

If you are creating a gem, it is better to include gems you depend on in your `.gemspec` file

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  ...
  spec.add_dependency "gem-name-whatev", "~> 1.5" # just like Gemfile
  spec.add_development_dependency "other-gem"
  ...
end
```

Comment: This isn't about requiring other gems, it's about Bundler auto-requiring my own gem's files. Apologies if I wasn't clear.